# Office365 Reports via Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch various usage reports for Office365 using Graph API. I created an Azure AD app and added the following permissions:

- Read All Usage Reports (Reports.Read.All)
- Read Directory Data (Directory.Read.All)

Admin also gave a consent.

I am experiencing a problem when I'm trying to fetch different usage reports. The following response is returned

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownTenantId",
        "message": "We do not recognize this tenant ID {actual tenant id}. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "545e7b8e-95b1-49bd-8d14-e47bf8e81cab",
            "date": "2018-06-01T11:36:32"
        }
    }
}
```

However, other endpoints are functional, e.g. I am able to fetch a list of users and organization info.

We just purchased an Office365 subscription today for testing and development. Is there a delay before report endpoints can be accessed? Or does anybody have an idea what might be the problem?

Edit:

Some of the endpoints that are returning the "UnknownTenantId" error are:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSkypeForBusinessActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D7')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOneDriveActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
```

Endpoints that return valid responses:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
```

The only thing that I'm explicitly setting in requests is an Authorization header, in the following form:

```
Authorization: Bearer token_value
```

Comment: Please make sure you include the code your _executing_, not just the error you're getting as a result. There isn't enough here to go on at the moment.

Comment: I'm currently testing the endpoints that we're planning to use with Postman, so there isn't much code available. I'll edit the question and provide some example URLs.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the reports are not yet available. If I try to download them from the reports section in admin center, I get the same error. I'll just need to wait a couple of days more before confirming this.

Comment: The endpoints work now - I'm getting a valid response. It took around 3 days before the data became available. However, I didn't find this in a documentation and the error is a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior - got a new trial license for o365 yesterday.. and some APIs are working (e.g., /v1.0/users/), but the reporting ones (e.g., v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserCounts(period='D7')) are failing with the UnknownTenantId code.

Comment: @AmitBhosle Judging by my experience, I think that you just need to wait a day or two. You can check if there are reports available under the reports page in O365 admin center. If there's no data there, endpoints won't work. After the reports became available in admin center, the endpoints became functional too.

Comment: Hi @shtrule - yup.. that's what it seems like. It started working after 3-4 days. Guess it takes a few days for new account information to get propagated to the reporting systems. Thanks.