# o365 Reports API could not fetch Reports

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, office365

When I try to call API requests for Reports, I'm getting following error, the sample API in Graph explorer for `/user/<tenant-id>` are working fine. For Reports i could not get the results for [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveActivityUserCounts(period='D7')?$format=application/json](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveActivityUserCounts(period=%27D7%27)?$format=application/json).

Although in admin reports, the reports are not being generated as I've made this trial account recently.

Can anyone please help with the steps I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
"code": "UnknownError",
"message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"UnknownTenantId\",\"message\":\"We do not recognize this tenant ID 5b1afc8e-xxxx-4842-xxxx-xxxxxx. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again.\"}}",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@usergg123

This error occurs when the usage report is not ready.

Request you to got to the Admin Portal and access this [Usage Reports](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home?/homepage#/reportsUsage)

Portal.office.com -> Admin Tab -> Show all -> Reports -> Usage

See whether you are seeing the below page :

[image]

If it says **no data** , ideally means that the usage report has not been populated for the tenant.

[image]

You re likely to encounter this issue.  Like suggested, it might take 48 hours to build the initial report for a new tenant.

A similar discussion occured here : [Office365 Reports via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642799/office365-reports-via-graph-api)

Comment: thanks. its is solved now. yes, the reports were not loaded properly as it takes 48 hrs, now i can fetch reports.

Comment: Also, i could not find proper docs on the charges for using the o365 APIs. does it cost?  does it come under o365 subscription package or have to upgrade on azure after the trial ends?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling - You have throttling. No you are not charged for issuing a graph request.